How to run flask shell in elastic beanstalk environment
I have a functional Flask app in an elastic beanstalk environment.
I can access it through ssh with eb ssh, navigate in folders.
I know that the app is located in /var/app/current/instance and virtual env /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate.
When I try to 'flask --app application.py shell' with virtual env activated it failed because my mandatory customs env var and database credentials provided by Elastic Beanstalk are missing.
I'm expecting success to enter in my Flask shell in order to interact with my app and my models.
I tried to print my custom env var and the ones related to the database. They are missing despite my app is working well.
Edit : finally found the answer, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65059905/22072380
I needed to export env variables located in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env as root (sudo su - ) with
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)

